# Redirecting user to homescreen when login with google

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

i have an app with google authentication. I'm using firebase. My Problem is when i login with google (with tapping a button) i can't go my app's homepage. I want once the user logs in go to homepage and never comeback login screen. I found quite a few resources on the internet. But none of them are out of date and the codes are not working. How can i solve that? Here is my code.

[my flutter code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlMYn.png)

i want to go homeScreen.dart file and HomeScreen widget.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the sign in method finishes, just redirect the user to Homescreen

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     //All of your widget's code
     //your button's code
     onPressed: (){
           signInWithGoogle(context);
     }
}

void signInWithGoogle(BuildContext context) async {
     // all your code to sign in 
     Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => HomeScreen());
}
```

Comment: Yeah but its not working. when i use navigator.push i get this error

"Undefined name 'context'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name."

Comment: Wherever you are calling the function from, make sure to include "context" as an argument.

Comment: I'm grateful for your time @ChiefMalone
But my code still not working.

[link](https://carbon.now.sh/a9292dbb-3290-4527-ba42-9b763a3dfeec)

This is my code for sign in.
I'cant add nothing because there is a "return".
I got this code from google docs. So i can sign in correctly. But as i said i can't do nothing after sign in.

Comment: That was a wrong link. Sorry

[link for code](https://codeshare.io/29k8V1)

Comment: you need to just finish your action in the function. So after finishing the sign in, don't return it, and remove the return in your onPressed statement. If you notice the function I wrote has a return type of 'void' because in order to redirect, you don't need to return anything.